How to remove date hierarchy from model in Power BI
How can I remove hierarchy from the model and just have fields Start of year, Start of quarter and start of week.


Go to  File --> Options and Settings --> Options --> Current File -> Data Load
and turn  off 'Auto Date/Time' (under Time Intelligence)

Do that in your template file. that way you don't have to do it in every single file. A ton of the preset options in PowerBI are absolutely awful.
